# How to know which network inteface is using when I connect to a database through OleDbConnection in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, interface, oledbconnection

My computer has multi network interfaces (Wireless Network Connection, Local Area Connection, VPN, etc).

When I use OleDbConnection, in C#, connect to a database, how to know which network interface is using by the current DBConnection?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter? This is intentionally abstracted away and handled automatically by your operating system, and therefore depends on which operating system you use.

Comment: Hi, @glennsl, thanks for your reply. Yes, I need to logging every connect action. Thanks.